# Message passing notation vs. Dot notation and the value inside an NSArray

Tags: objective-c

I have this piece of code, and I would like the message notation equivalent:

```
cell.textLabel.text = self.dataArray[indexPath.row];
```

the best I can do is:

```
[[cell textLabel] setText: [ what goes here? ]];
```

Comment: What's wrong with `cell.textLabel.text = self.dataArray[indexPath.row];`?  Or, failing that, `[[cell textLabel] setText: self.dataArray[indexPath.row]];`?

Comment: I can't read dot notation. When I started programming I learnt Smalltalk. I found it so clear and logical. If I see dot notation it makes me assume there is something going on under the hood that I don't understand, makes me feel uneasy. So now that I'm learning Objective-C I feel refreshed when I see message notation everywhere and I absolutely LOVE the brackets (they make the execution order very clear). I'm NOT kidding!

Comment: To each his own.  As I said below it's confusing to the novice, since the exact same function can often be expressed several ways, and in other cases you *can't* use the dot notation.  Objective-C is not a particularly "uniform" language.

Comment: Smalltalk is beautiful, C is concise. This dot notation thing, I think, was only added to ease the transition for people from other "modern" object oriented languages which are littered with the dot. My take is that it makes people oblivious to what is going on under the hood and more dependent on the compiler to do its job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fully expanded version is this:

```
[[cell textLabel] setText:[[self dataArray] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
```

However, this is absolutely no difference between that and what you originally posted. They are identical to the compiler.

---

The two kinds of syntax being used here are:

## Dot Syntax

This is for `-foo` or `-setFoo:` methods:

```
cell.textLabel -> [cell textLabel]

cell.textLabel.text = ... [[cell textLabel] setText:...]
```

## Subscripting

This is for `-objectAtIndex:` and `-setObject:atIndex:` methods (if it's an `NSArray`), and `objectForKey:` and `-setObject:forKey:` methods (if it's an `NSDictionary`):

```
dataArray[indexPath.row] -> [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

The actual methods invoked are `objectAtIndexedSubscript:`..., but they're analogous to the more common `objectAtIndex:` methods. For more information on this syntax, [check out the Clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#object-subscripting).

Comment: It isn't really "subscripting", it's "message" notation.

Comment: @HotLicks using the `[]` syntax to index into an array or dictionary is called subscripting. But since these all end up invoking methods, it is "sending messages".

Comment: Very complete answer and also has a little depth to explain other stuff to novices, please add [[cell textLabel] setText: [[self dataArray] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]]; at the top so we can message notate the indexPath.row part too. I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: In any event it's confusing as heck to the novice.  Several different ways to represent the exact same function.

Comment: @DaveDeLong you need to change dataArray to _dataArray or [self dataArray].

Answer (score 1):

```
[[cell textLabel] setText: [self dataArray][indexPath row]];
```

or:

```
[[cell textLabel] setText: [_dataArray[indexPath row]];
```

I assume that the ivar for self.dataArray is _dataArray (default);

or you can call

```
[[cell textLabel] setText: [[self dataArray] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
```